# Decoding Encoded Audio Data (MP3s, etc) on Android Without Playing It

Tags: android, audio, mp3, decoding

Short version: What is the best way to get data encoded in an MP3 (and ideally in an
AAC/Ogg/WMA) into a Java array or ByteBuffer that I can then
manipulate?

I'm putting together a program that has slowing down and speeding up
sound files as one of its features.  This works fine for WAV files,
which are a header plus the exact binary data that needs to be sent to
the speaker, and now I need to implement it for MP3 (ideally, this
would also support AAC, Ogg, and WMA, but since those are less popular
formats this is not required).  Android does not expose an interface
to decode the MP3 without playing it, so I need to create that
interface.

Three options present themselves, though I'm open to others:

1)  Write my own decoder.  I already have a functional frame detector
that I was hoping to use for option (3), and now should only need to
implement the Huffman decoding tables.

2)  Use JLayer, or an equivalent Java library, to handle the
decoding.  I'm not entirely clear on what the license ramifications
are here.

3)  Connect to the libmedia library/MediaPlayerService.  This is what
SoundPool does, and the amount of use of that service make me believe
that while it's officially unstable, that implementation isn't going
anywhere.  This means writing JNI code to connect to the service, but
I'm finding that that's a deep rabbit hole.  At the surface, I'm
having trouble with the sp<> template.

Comment: did you succeed in decoding audio data? If so, how did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I did that with libmad and the NDK. JLayer is way to slow and the media framework is a moving target. You can find info and source code at http://apistudios.com/hosted/marzec/badlogic/wordpress/?p=231

Comment: This seems like a somewhat limited solution, since libmad is licensed under the GPL; meaning that to use  it, I would need to license my app under the GPL, which is not something I was planning on doing (and it sounds like you may be in the same boat).

This is part of what made JLayer attractive:  It's LGPL-licensed.  Android is Apache licensed, so you're really in the clear.  A significant part of me doubts that the media framework is a moving target:  At this point, it is ingrained into so many higher-level objects (MediaPlayer and SoundPool, mostly) that I doubt they will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but [mp3transform](http://code.google.com/p/mp3transform/) is LGPL.

Comment: android doesnt support javax.sound. this lib uses it, so it is not useful for android